# Given Closed $U \subset C$, Closed $V\subset D$, $ C,\ D$ Both Closed,Show $U \cup V$ is closed in $C \cup D$

Tags: general-topology

Given closed $U \subset C$, closed $V \subset D$, $C,\ D$ both closed.

Show that $U \cup V$ is closed in $C \cup D$.

Is the condition that $C,\ D$ being closed necessary here?

Comment: C,D each has the usual subspace topology of some space U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. consider a closed subset $U$ around the boundary of $C$ but such that $U$ is open in $D\setminus C$. Finally chose $V=\emptyset$

---

Concrete: $C = [0,1)$ and $D=[1, 2]$, $U = [1/2, 1), V = \emptyset$ with the usual $\mathbb R$-subspace tolopogies. Then
$$[1/2, 1) \subset [0,2]$$
is no longer closed.